# Game programming, why implement Runnable?

Tags: java

Most games are programmed in this structure:

```
[GAME LOOP]
Update method(ticks based on the delta time)
Render method(ticks as fast as possible)
```

Why can you not implement `Runnable` and actually create an infinite loop:

```
while(true){
    update();
    render();
}
```

You can really sum up all of this to "Why use threads?"

I never tried it, but i would like to get a wise answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Games(UI rendering) should not hang when some background work is in progress.

If you say

```
while(true){
    update(); //say it takes 1 min
    render();
}
```

Your Game will not respond for the 1 minute `update()` method is taking to execute.

If you would have written like below

```
while(true){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
         public void run() {
            update(); //say it takes 1 min
         }
    });
    t.start();
    render();
}
```

`update()` would run **asynchronously**  (by the means of a separate thead), **parallely**, *without halting* your main Game program

Comment: Finally, this is the example that i could understand.. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Also multicore system may be able to run severeal threads in parallel. This may make the whole program run faster - that is normaly desireable in games with graphics.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example, the `update` method needs to run at regular intervals in order to adjust the game world at a suitable pace.

The `render` method must run in a separate thread in case it causes the `update` method to be delayed, or to execute ahead of time.

Comment: So your saying i need the thread to interval them? for example  Thread.sleep

Comment: Typically a regularly scheduled event (like your `update` method) is handled by a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) or a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).